# Please remove those 'The site's Public Beta will begin in x minutes countdowns'

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, beta-phase

It seems that each site in private beta shows a count down after 7 days, like [image] independent, of the fact if and when it is really going public beta. I remember to have seen a delay of some hours at the start of http://dba.stackexchange.com.

I think it would be better not to show such misleading information.

Even better would be to distinguish between the cases where there are some technical delays or when the site is hold intensionally in private beta, which seems to be the case with [Healthcare IT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The countdown made sense back in the pre-[community-team](https://stackexchange.com/about/team) glory days, when developers still ran the show, and private/public beta launches worked like clockwork. But now that more factors are at play, and we're actually monitoring the health of private betas, you're right:  it makes more sense to remove the countdown, so that's what we've done.